# Setting side mouse buttons to "Back" and "Forward" in browser, nautilus, etc

Tags: mouse

I have a Cyborg R.A.T.3 mouse with two side buttons. In Windows, by default, those side buttons work as the "Back" and "Forward" buttons in apps like Firefox, Chrome, Explorer, etc.

How do I do the same for Ubuntu?

My xorg.conf entry for the R.A.T.3 looks like this:

```
# RAT3 mouse
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "Mouse Remap"
  MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3 Mouse"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 13 14"
EndSection
```

...with the "Back" and "Forward" buttons on my mouse being 8 and 9 respectively.

Comment: If you open a terminal and run `xinput list`, can you see your mouse? If yes, can you run `xinput test ID`, where ID is the number you found from `xinput list`? Which button numbers are reported for your Back and Forward buttons? As far as I know, the numbers should be 8 and 9. You can reassign the numbers with `xinput --set-button-map`.

Comment: Hi elmicha. That is indeed the case. The two side buttons are assigned to 8 and 9.

However, this does not help with then assigning those buttons to "Back" and "Forward" in Firefox, nautilus, etc. I have no doubt it's possible, but I just don't know how to do it :)

Comment: I also just added the R.A.T.3 entry from my xorg.conf to the original question.

Comment: If you can see the buttons 8 and 9 with `xinput test ID`, Firefox and Chromium should work with them out of the box, IMHO. I tried it with two VMs that are rather fresh (unconfigured), one Natty and one Oneiric, and the buttons work there, too. What Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: Somewhat strangely it has started to work. Possibly a result of rebooting. Thanks for your help elmicha. I wouldn't have known about `xinput test` otherwise!

Comment: @thecosmicfrog Can you please post what worked as the answer (and accept it)? This helps your rep and makes it easier for others to find the answer.

Comment: One issue I had with the R.A.T. 7 mouse is that for some reason my "back" and "forward" buttons were mapped as `2` and `9` respectively. Changing it back to `8` and `9` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` fixed the issue for me.